# How to open pptx file with an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, powerpoint

I would like to open a PowerPoint file from my app.  The file is stored in my assets folder.  I use this code:

```
Uri helpfile = Uri.parse("content://com.example.myapp/Tutorial.pptx");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(helpfile, "*/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

I have registered a ContentProvider class in my manifest.

```
<provider android:name="com.example.myapp.Provider"
android:authorities="com.example.myapp"
android:grantUriPermissions="true"
android:exported="true" />
```

I have also tried:

```
intent.setType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
```

I get asked what app I want to complete the action, I choose POLARIS Office 5 and a Toast appears "Not a supported document type."  If I launch the PPTX file from ASTRO File Manager, POLARIS opens right away.

What am I missing?